# MVC 5 Entity Framework pass a where clause in SelectList so that the dropdown gets right data

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have a model that looks like this:

```
namespace NewHireApp.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public partial class NewHire
{
    public SelectList ADList1 { get; set; }
}
}
```

Controller is like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewHire()
{
  List<ActiveDirectory> objadlist4 = (from data in objentity.ActiveDirectories select   data).ToList();

  ActiveDirectory objAD1 = new ActiveDirectory();

        objAD1.displayName = "";
        objAD1.department = "";
        objAD1.Id = 0;
        objadlist4.Insert(0, objAD1);

  SelectList objmodeldata4 = new SelectList(objadlist4, "displayName", "displayName", 0);

  NewHire objadmodel = new NewHire();
  objadmodel.ADList1 = objmodeldata4;

  return View(objadmodel);
  }
```

And a view like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @*style="display:none"*@
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HR_Emp, "HR Person:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HR_Emp, Model.ADList1, new { @id = "ddlHR", @style = "width:500px;", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HR_Emp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

All I would like to do is drill down so all I am returning are the people from a specific department but I do not know how to do that.  Can someone please help?  I would imagine I would need to do this within the controller but sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a where clause on your select.  Something like this:

```
List<ActiveDirectory> objadlist4 = 
   (from data in objentity.ActiveDirectories 
    where data.department == "myDept"
    select data).ToList();
```

Comment: This errored out.  Not sure what to do.  It says Too many characters in character literal.

Comment: It should be "myDept". Notice the use of double-quotes. You can only have a single character between single-quotes.

Comment: My apologies.  I have been doing too much AngularJS these days!